# Populate FusionCharts with XML data AJAX

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, fusioncharts

Hi I have a js file that uses ajax to get a XML doc from a php script . The XML file forms the data to draw a Fusion Chart. I know I am getting the XML data ok but FusionCharts will not draw it . I would really appreciate any help , thanks

```
(FusionCharts.js is included earlier in my script) 

if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {

XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "chart.php?job="+job, true);

XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() { 
if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&  XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
var xdoc = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;

     var chart1 = new FusionCharts("Pie3D.swf", "chart1Id", "400", "300", "0", "1"); 
 chart1.setDataXML(xdoc);
     chart1.render("chart1div");
```

**chart.php produces this XML data**

```
<chart caption='ADI Chart Test ' >
  <set label='Driver' value='12.25' />
  <set label='Other Staff' value='223.21' />
  <set label='Equipment' value='0.00' />
  <set label='Additional Items' value='0.00' />
  <set label='Vehicle Fuel' value='0.00' />
  <set label='Accomodation' value='0.00' />
  <set label='Generator Fuel' value='0.00' />
</chart>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "chart.php?job="+job, true);
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
            var xdoc = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;
            var chart1 = new FusionCharts("Pie3D.swf", "chart1Id", "400", "300", "0", "1"); 
            chart1.setDataXML(xdoc);
            chart1.render("chart1div");
```

Thanks.. it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though that you have a 'chart1div', even though it i.e. the Div is not defined.
For this, you would need to define a Div.

Also, try using responseText in place of responseXML. Here, the former returns a string while the latter returns a XML document object.

Example:
var xdoc = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;

:)

Answer (score 0):

Does the "Pie3D.swf" live in the same root directory that you're working from?

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the XML as string from chart.php.....
And trythe following code.

```
FusionCharts.RenderChart("/Charts/FCF_Pie3D.swf", "", $strXML, "ResourceVsCO1", "400", "200", false, false);
```

strXML is the string contain xml return from chart.ph